# Programming language supporting infinitary rewriting of regular term graphs?

Tags: functional-programming, term-rewriting-systems

Do any practical programming languages support term graph rewriting of infinite but regular terms? For example the toy language CoCaml [1] supports computations on infinite regular streams. Coq supports coinduction [2] but not infinitary rewriting, as far as I can tell. By "infinite regular term graph", I mean those inhabitants of coalgebraic datatypes that can be defined in terms of finitely many equations.

- [1] Jean-Baptiste Jeannin, Dexter Kozen, Alexandra Silva (2017)
  [CoCaml: Functional Programming with Regular Coinductive Types](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/~kozen/papers/cocaml.pdf)
- [2] Yves Bertot, Ekaterina Komendantskaya (2008)
  [Inductive and Coinductive Components of Corecursive Functions in Coq](https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00277075v1/document)

Answer (score 8):

Yes, [Prolog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolog).

The specification of unification in the Prolog standard omits the [*occurs check*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occurs_check), and as a result [when this spec is properly implemented](https://dtai.cs.kuleuven.be/projects/ALP/newsletter/archive_93_96/net/impl/occur.html#:%7E:text=Another%20point%20that,to%20rational%20trees.) variables range over rational trees. Additionally,  many Prolog (such as [SWI Prolog](http://www.swi-prolog.org/) and [YAP](https://www.dcc.fc.up.pt/%7Evsc/Yap/)) implementations support [*tabling*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolog#Tabling), which permits defining and using coinductively defined predicates.